# fit data with x axis already formatted with dateticks() MATLAB

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have been at this for hours, i feel like the simple problems take the longest which is annoying. I cannot seem to fit a curve to my data, i've tried fit(), polyval(), and I cannot get them to work. I think the problem is, my x axis is in months, not really numbers so the functions hate me right now. Here is my code:

```
startDate = datenum('01-01-1985');
endDate = datenum('12-31-1985');
month = linspace(startDate,endDate,12);
waterLevel1985 = [75.2 75.3 75.4 75.6 75.7 75.75 75.6 75.5 75.3 75.25 75.2 75.25];

p = polyfit(month,waterLevel1985,4);   %error is here apparently...
x = 1:0.5:12;
bestFit = polyval(p,x);
plot(month,waterLevel1985,x,bestFit)

ax = gca;
ax.XTick = month;
datetick('x','mmm','keepticks')
```

When i plot, I get a graph with jan feb mar apr....etc as my x axis, and the water level values for1985 on my y axis. If I just put plot (month, waterlevel1985, 'r+') I don't get a fitted curve to my data (which looks closest to a 4th degree polynomial). Please help me do this, I cannot figure it out!

EDIT: I've even tried putting [1:1:12] in the polyfit function instead of month and it still won't work. I've been fooling around with polyfit and polyval but they won't work for me. I've even tried the following:

```
startDate = datenum('01-01-1985');
endDate = datenum('12-31-1985');
month = linspace(startDate,endDate,12);
waterLevel1985 = [75.2 75.3 75.4 75.6 75.7 75.75 75.6 75.5 75.3 75.25 75.2 75.25];

p = polyfit([1:1:12],waterLevel1985,4);
x = 1:0.5:12;
bestFit = polyval(p,x);
plot(month,waterLevel1985,'r+')
hold on
plot(x, bestFit)
hold off

ax = gca;
ax.XTick = month;
datetick('x','mmm','keepticks')
```

Comment: If your data is evenly spaced (one observation per month), just make a dummy `x` variable `1:12` and do your fitting/evaluation for that, but when you plot use `month`.

Comment: But you have left off the code that is giving you the problem! Please add your fitting and plotting code back in.

Comment: @David I tried this, and still for some odd reason it won't work. I've cleared and tried again, still nothing. I want the graph to have the water levels on the y axis and 12 months of the year on the x axis, then I want to plot my original data plot(month,waterLevel1985,'r+') and then plot a curve that is fitted to that data, that's why I have my polyfit and polyval functions.

Comment: The problem is, when I use polyfit(month,waterLevel1985,4) it gives me a warning about my fit being a bad fit and it doesn't plot the curve. When I use polyfit([1:1:12], waterLevel1985,4) it won't plot the fit again but this time without a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what was happening was that the numerical conditioning of the polynomial fitting was very bad because the `month` values were very large. (Maybe).

I rescaled the month values to lie in `[0,1]` then did the fitting, then made the plot and it seems to work now.

```
startDate = datenum('01-01-1985')
endDate = datenum('12-31-1985')
month = linspace(startDate,endDate,12);
waterLevel1985 = [75.2 75.3 75.4 75.6 75.7 75.75 75.6 75.5 75.3 75.25 75.2 75.25];
month2=linspace(0,1,48); %// finer grid for plotting
%// Now transform month into [0,1] and fit the polynomial
p = polyfit((month-startDate)/(endDate-startDate),waterLevel1985,4)
plot(month,waterLevel1985,'o',month2*(endDate-startDate)+startDate,polyval(p,month2))
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = month;
datetick('x','mmm','keepticks')
```

which gives this
[image]

Comment: I am a little unsure what you did but this is magic. Thank you kind sir.